# Intermittent INSERT failure to mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Simple php/mysql INSERT such as

`mysql_query("INSERT INTO dispatch VALUES('1234','$name','$address')");`

intermittently fails. I've set it up to trap when it happens and put the user back onto the form with the re-populated data so they can try again, however once it fails, it will never insert. I've tried re-establishing the connections, creating a new connection, I'm at a total loss here. Anybody have any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Result of `DESCRIBE dispatch`

```
 ticketnum int(11) NO PRI auto_increment 
 callername tinyblob NO
 callerphone tinyblob YES 
 request longblob YES 
 clientname tinyblob NO 
 callcounty varchar(30) YES 
 clientphone tinyblob YES 
 dispatcher varchar(30) NO 
 dispatched varchar(3) NO
 rectime datetime NO
 dispatchtime datetime YES
 timetodispatch time YES
 worker varchar(30) YES
 restime datetime NO
 timetores time NO
 resolution varchar(120) NO
 notes longblob YES 
 recordnum varchar(15) YES 
 dob date YES
```

EDITED TO ADD:

I found it. My first hint was [here](http://abbyandwin.net/blog/2010/09/15/debian5-lenny-and-mysql-server-5-1-x/). Apparently, MySQL 5.1.49 has some stability issues in conjunction with Debian (I'm using Ubuntu Server). Further searching after this hint describes some very similar situations. Currently, I'm reconfiguring and installing MySQL 5.0.51. Hopefully, this will help put a stop to the nonsense :)

Thanks to you all for your help!

Comment: Perhaps you're violating a unique constraint?

Comment: Don't see how, and I'm getting no error, except that mysql_affected_rows() assures me it's not inserting.

Comment: Can you show us the output of `DESCRIBE dispatch` ?

Comment: `ticketnum  int(11)   NO   PRI   auto_increment
callername  tinyblob   NO  
callerphone  tinyblob   YES  
request  longblob   YES  
clientname  tinyblob   NO  
callcounty  varchar(30) YES  
clientphone  tinyblob   YES  
dispatcher  varchar(30) NO  
dispatched  varchar(3)  NO  
rectime  datetime   NO  
dispatchtime  datetime   YES  
timetodispatch  time  YES  
worker  varchar(30)  YES  
restime datetime  NO  
timetores time    NO  
resolution varchar(120) NO  
notes  longblob  YES  
recordnum varchar(15)  YES  
dob  date  YES`

Comment: I'm confused by your `INSERT`. You appear to be putting a fixed value into `ticketnum`, which is an auto_incrementing field. In addition, you're putting the value of a variable called `$address` into `callerphone`... is that what you intend to do?

Comment: that was just an example, to show the structure of my insert statement. The variables in the actual insert statement are correct, I just didn't want to put all those variables into the post. And thanks for the edit, I didn't know how to put that in there.

Comment: Is that really how you are doing your insert statements? Because it's very open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: I'm sanitizing the variables before I insert

Comment: Still dangerous.  It's preferrable to use prepared statements (aka parameterized queries).  With the method you're using, all it takes is one missed line of code, forgetting to sanitize one variable, and you go a problem.  With prepared statements, there's no chance of accidentally forgetting to sanitize something, because there's no way not to.

Comment: Makes sense..but if I can't figure out why this is happening, it's a moot point.

Comment: Since you found your answer yourself, I would add an answer below, include said details and mark as the answer. This will help others in the future if someone has the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. My first hint was [here](http://abbyandwin.net/blog/2010/09/15/debian5-lenny-and-mysql-server-5-1-x/). Apparently, MySQL 5.1.49 has some stability issues in conjunction with Debian (I'm using Ubuntu Server). Further searching after this hint describes some very similar situations. Currently, I'm reconfiguring and installing MySQL 5.0.51. Hopefully, this will help put a stop to the nonsense :)

Thanks to you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using persistent connections to the DB? Maybe the issue lies in the connection method to your DB and not the actual `INSERT` statement.  Have you checked your MYSQL/SYS logs?

To clarify, usually your MYSQL log would be in `/var/log/mysql` or related area (this example is for a linux debian system, will vary for your system).

This are least lets you see **IF** there are any mysql errors, ie run out of resources, etc;

Comment: not using persistent connections, just the error log, not sure where to find MYSQL/SYS logs..I've never had to get this deep into it before

Comment: Okay, yes, I've checked the log there, and there's nothing out of the ordinary..the last restart, ready for connections, that's it. and this has happened since that.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to try this

put your field name into the query:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO dispatch(ticketnum,callername,...) VALUES('1234',$name,$address)");
```

I am assuming the $name and $address are variables. from this query above align the field names with values you want to insert. like the way i have here will not work for sure, cos you have the `int(11) and String type mismatch`, ticketnum is autogenerated value, change accordingly to fit your requirments...

create a stored stored procedure, that will make things easy ..

Comment: I did try that, last week. It made no difference. Not the stored procedure, though. However, I shouldn't be getting the intermittent failure even if I'm not using a stored procedure yet.

Comment: can you make more clear, to which fields you want to insert the values. And then make sure the other fields have default value..

Comment: well, that's the thing, I've gone through all the fields one by one, checked the defaults and my insert variables and tried loads of different insert values to be sure it wasn't my own sanitizing or anything else causing it. It's really weird and there's no way I can be the only one who's had this problem..I'm starting to think maybe something's corrupt or the server needs reinstalled or god knows what..I think the next thing I'll have to try is putting the whole thing on another machine to see if it's hardware..it almost acts as if the connection is being dropped.